# Java private boolean asking for return while return is there

Tags: java, boolean

I got a weird error in my java code:

```
error: This method must return a result of type boolean
```

Why is this public boolean giving this error while I added return true and return false to it?

My code:

```
public void render(float delta) {

    ....................
    .... Other code ....
    ....................

    if (hasBallCollision(player)){
        ball.setZy(3 * screenheight);
        difficulty += 0.1;
    }
}

private boolean hasBallColission(Player player){
    if(ball.getX()+8*screenwidth>player.getX()-40*screenwidth&&ball.getX()+8*screenwidth<player.getX()+40*screenwidth){
        if(ball.getY()>player.getY()&&ball.getY()<player.getY()+16*screenheight){
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading/helping!

Comment: Because your method doesn't return anything if the first condition is true and the second condition is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all the pathways in your `hasBallColission` (you probably mean "collision") return a value.

In your nested `if` statement, there's no `else` statement.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid leaking in all paths. Always define your "return value" first.

```
private boolean hasBallColission(Player player){
    boolean rtnValue = false;
    if(ball.getX()+8*screenwidth>player.getX()-40*screenwidth&&ball.getX()+8*screenwidth<player.getX()+40*screenwidth){
        if(ball.getY()>player.getY()&&ball.getY()<player.getY()+16*screenheight){
           rtnValue = true;
        }
    }
    return rtnValue;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a return statement in all paths :

```
if (ball.getX()+8*screenwidth>player.getX()-40*screenwidth&&ball.getX()+8*screenwidth<player.getX()+40*screenwidth) {
    if (ball.getY()>player.getY()&&ball.getY()<player.getY()+16*screenheight) {
        return true;
    }
    // missing return statement here
} else {
    return false;
}
```